# Problemas con setTimeout al llamarlo recursivamente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema en la creación de un piano en JavaScript leyendo una partitura de un txt, es en la parte de cuando creo los acordes (tocar varias notas al mismo tiempo) que los separo con || cuando intento tocarlos funciona, pero **cuando añado mas de dos notas al acorde**, el tempo de las demás notas tiene problemas y empieza a tocar varias a la vez mi problema creo que radica en esta linea dentro del acorde:

**setTimeout(playMusicSheet,duration[durationnote]);**

Funcion a la que le paso la partitura

```
export function readMusicSheet(musicSheet) {
  //Separo la partitura en un array
  musicSheet = musicSheet.trim();
  const musicSheetDOM = document.getElementById("music-sheet");
  musicSheetDOM.classList.add("music-sheet");
  const keys = musicSheet.split("\n");


  //Recorro el array y lo escribo por pantalla
  keys.forEach(key => {
    const keyDOM = document.createElement("li");
    keyDOM.classList.add("music-sheet-key");
    keyDOM.innerHTML = key;
    musicSheetDOM.appendChild(keyDOM);

  });
}

let actualKeyIndex = 0;
var playPiano;
var playPiano2;
```

Funcion que reproduce la partitura

```
export function playMusicSheet(callback) {
  const musicSheetDOM = document.getElementById("music-sheet");
  const musicSheetKeysDOM = musicSheetDOM.childNodes;
  const musicSheetKeyDOM = musicSheetKeysDOM[actualKeyIndex];
  musicSheetKeyDOM.classList.add("play");
  const key = musicSheetKeyDOM.innerText;
  console.log(key);
  /* call function soundKey and pass variable key */


  //Funcion que se reproduce cuando encuentra un acorde es decir tocar varias notas a la vez
  if (key.includes('||') || key.includes('|')) {
    const acorde = key.split("||");

    //recorremos el array de la linea del acorde
      acorde.forEach(acorde => {

        //Lo que esta a la izquieda de la coma es la nota
        const note = acorde.split(",")[0];

        //Lo que esta a la derecha de la coma es la duracion
        const durationnote = acorde.split(",")[1];

        //Se envia a la funcion para que suene con audioContext
        soundPartiture(keys[note], duration[durationnote]);

        //Se pulsa la tecla que debe presionarse
        playKey(note, true);

        //Cuando finaliza la nota se desactiva la clase play
        setTimeout(() => {
            playKey(note, false);
            musicSheetKeyDOM.classList.remove("play");
        }, duration[durationnote]);

        //Se llama recursivamente para que me lo haga en cada nota
        playPiano = setTimeout(playMusicSheet, duration[durationnote]);

      });

      //Limpiame los timeout
      clearTimeout(playPiano);
      clearTimeout(playPiano2);
      console.log(key);


  } else {

    //Esto se hara si la solo se toca una nota
    const note = key.split(",")[0];
    const durationnote = key.split(",")[1];

    soundPartiture(keys[note], duration[durationnote]);
    playKey(note, true);
    playPiano = setTimeout(function () {
      playKey(note, false);
      musicSheetKeyDOM.classList.remove("play");

    }, duration[durationnote]);


    playPiano2 = setTimeout(playMusicSheet, duration[durationnote]);
    
  }
  //se llama a la siguiente nota
  actualKeyIndex++;
}
```

La funcion de que suene el sonido la realizo asi aunque unicamente utilizo la nota no la duracion

```
  export function soundPartiture(note, duration) {
  let audioContext = new AudioContext();

    var now = audioContext.currentTime;
    let mainGainNode = audioContext.createGain();
    let osc = audioContext.createOscillator();

    osc.type = "sine";

    //le paso el valor de la nota ejemplo: C4
    osc.frequency.value = note;


    mainGainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0, now);
    mainGainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, now + 0.01);
    osc.start(now);
    mainGainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, now + 1);
    osc.stop(now + 1);

    osc.connect(mainGainNode);
    mainGainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    //cierro los audiocontext para que no se saturen en el navegador ya 
    que tiene limite de 50
    setTimeout(() => { audioContext.close();}, 1500);


    
 }
```

Y la funcion de tocar la nota la realizo pasandole la nota y un evento

```
  export function playKey(key, isDown) {
  const keyDOM = allDOMKeys[key];
  if (isDown) {
    keyDOM.classList.add("active");



} else {
    keyDOM.classList.remove("active");
}
}
```

La partitura esta en este formato

```
F5,5
E5,5
F5,1||D4,2
A5,1
E5,1||C4,2
D5,5
C5,5
```

Comment: Me falta ver cómo llamas a estas dos funciones y los datos que reciben para entender el escenario.

Comment: Vale actualice la pregunta añadiendo los dos metodos que llamo y en cuanto a los datos, tengo en un objeto todas las frecuencias de las notas es decir si cojo key[C4] me dara el valor de la frecuencia 261.62 y la duracion tengo otro objeto al que si le paso duracion[1] me sacara 1000 a y el fichero donde lee la partitura tiene este formato                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
F5,5
E5,5
F5,1||D4,2
A5,1
E5,1||C4,2
D5,5
C5,5